# How can I cite a dataset for which no Google Scholar entry is available?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite [this](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/rwbs7645hg/1) dataset in my paper. Although the  creators mentioned how to cite the dataset, I am confused about what **I should write in the `.bib` file as there was no entry for this dataset on Google Scholar.**

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why does the lack of an entry in Google Scholar create confusion?

Comment: I used to copy the BibTeX contents of G Scholar for .bib file . Never created a citation in .bib file on my own. So was facing difficulties to create it from scratch on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
@misc{10.17632/rwbs7645hg.1,
    author = {Leobardo S\'{a}nchez-Velasco  and Manuel Arias-Montiel and Enrique Guzm\'{a}n-Ram\'{i}rez},
    year = {2019}, 
    title = {EMG data of the Myo Armband}, 
    howpublished= {Mendeley Data, V1, doi: 10.17632/rwbs7645hg.1},
}
```

[image]

If your bibstyle supports the `doi` field, you could include

```
doi = {10.17632/rwbs7645hg.1},
```

ADDENDUM

I thought a few comments on the `@misc{` entry might be useful.  This entry serves as a fallback for references that do not fit into any entry type. (Online content is a typical use.)

In classic [BibTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf), only the following fields are recognized: `author`, `title`, `year`, `howpublished`, `note`. Each of these is optional (BibTeX will check to see that at least one is not empty).  Specific bibliography styles (`.bst`) may add additional fields to this list, such as `doi` or `url`.

In [BibLaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), the following fields are required: `author` or `editor`,`title`, `year` or `date`. A large number of additional fields are optional, including `doi` and `url` (see documentation for details).

As noted in a different answer to this question, it's good practice to add `{..}` around letters that you wish to print in upper case. Many `.bst` styles will apply a text transformation to the title, perhaps to change the field to lower case except for the first letter.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest something like the following. If you're using standard `bibtex` then you need to escape the accented characters in the names. Also, I wouldn't depend on Google Scholar `.bib` entries generally. They are often quite bizarrely wrong.

```
@misc{Sanchez-VelascoArias-MontielGuzman-Ramirez2019,
    Author = {Sánchez-Velasco, Leobardo and  Arias-Montiel, Manuel and  Guzmán-Ramírez, Enrique},
    Doi = {10.17632/RWBS7645HG.1},
    Howpublished = {Mendeley Data, V1},
    Publisher = {Mendeley},
    Title = {{EMG} data of the {Myo Armband}},
    Url = {https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/rwbs7645hg/1},
    Year = {2019},
    }
```

Comment: Hi, your solution worked too but I chose the other because it produced the closest output to what mentioned by the original creators.

Did you follow any rule to create the entry name - Sanchez-VelascoArias-MontielGuzman-Ramirez2019 ?

Comment: @Debbie My `.bib` manager (BibDesk on the Mac) creates keys for me based on the first three authors' names. Since these are all big names, the key is probably a bit unwieldy. The output should be the same for both except for my entry has a URL as well as a DOI. But you should put `{...}` around the capitalized parts of the title as I did in mine, since some styles will make them lower case, which you don't want.

Comment: But I reiterate my plea not to depend on Google Scholar for `.bib` entries. They're often wrong.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all these. Could you plz suggest an alternative to BibDesk in Ubuntu? Is there any rule to generate keys manually w/o using any S/W?

Comment: @Debbie A good alternative to BibDesk for Linux is [Jabref](https://www.jabref.org/). There are no specific rules for keys, it's mainly personal preference. I use the authors' last names (up to 3)+year because it allows me to add citations in my source roughly as they would appear in the output (my work uses author/year referencing exclusively) and it means I don't need to look up keys very often. Of course since you can't have duplicate keys, if you have two works by the same author in the same year, you need to make them distinct; for this I usually add a meaningful keyword from the title.

Comment: thanks a lot....